# Problems fetching JSON data to populate a dropdown list in HTML

Tags: html, json, drop-down-menu

I am having a hard time trying to fetch data from a JSON to populate options for a dropdown list in my HTML. The dropdown list doesn't show any options, but the fetching seems to work!
Please enlighten me by telling me what I'm doing that is wrong!

Here is part of my code about the dropdown list :

```
<div>
  <label for="devicemodel">Device :</label>
  <select id="deviceModel"></select>
</div>
```

Here is the script I am using to fetch data from a JSON. The fetching seems to work because the console.log returns the proper results in the console :

```
<script>
  // Function to fetch data from sheety
  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://api.sheety.co/45256646ee76deaa20e88c36a827fcc6/cms/feuille1');
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log('JSON data successfully fetched :', data);
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error when trying to fetch :', error);
    }
  }

  // Function to populate dropdown list with device models
  async function populateDeviceModels() {
    const selectElement = document.getElementById('deviceModel');
    
    // Get data from Sheety
    const jsonData = await fetchData();

    // Check if data was fetched succesfully
    if (jsonData) {
      // Navigate data and add every model to dropdown list
      jsonData.forEach(item => {
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = item.modelName;
        option.text = item.modelName;
        selectElement.appendChild(option);
      });
    }
  }

  // Call function to populate dropdown list at page loading
  populateDeviceModels();
</script>
```

And here is a snippet of what to console returns when running the program :

```
"JSON data successfully fetched :" // [object Object] 
{
  "feuille1": [
    {
      "modelName": "iphone11",
      "name": "iPhone 11",
      "id": 2
    },
```

Comment: jsonData is an object, not an array. Try `jsonData.feuille1.forEach`. Your browser's dev tools should have a debugger that you can use.

I also recommend taking a look at tech like Typescript and Zod whenever you feel comfortable. It adds a bit of complexity, in exchange for catching lots of errors sooner.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the below code. I debug your code and found that  jsonData is wrapped in an object with a key feuille1 containing an array, you need to access jsonData.feuille1 in your populateDeviceModels function.

```
<script>
    // Function to fetch data from Sheety
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('https://api.sheety.co/45256646ee76deaa20e88c36a827fcc6/cms/feuille1');
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log('JSON data successfully fetched:', data);
        return data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error when trying to fetch:', error);
      }
    }

    // Function to populate dropdown list with device models
    async function populateDeviceModels() {
  const selectElement = document.getElementById('deviceModel');

  // Get data from Sheety
  const jsonData = await fetchData();

  // Check if data was fetched successfully and has the expected structure
  if (jsonData && jsonData.feuille1 && Array.isArray(jsonData.feuille1)) {
    // Loop through the array and add each model to the dropdown list
    jsonData.feuille1.forEach(item => {
      const option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = item.modelName;
      option.text = item.modelName;
      selectElement.appendChild(option);
    });
  } else {
    console.error('Invalid or missing data structure:', jsonData);
  }
}

populateDeviceModels();
  </script>
```